# Conditional where clause in Select statement

Tags: sql, conditional-statements

I am using a stored procedure to generate a report based on parameters to SP. I have to join different where conditions depending upon parameters passed.

For ex.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Report_InventoryAging] 

@TitleFlag int=0, /*0-All veh, 1-Clear Title, 2-Without Clear Title*/

@CompName varchar(100) = 'ALL COMPANIES',

@CompBranchId varchar(50) = 'ALL',  /*All Offices*/

@StateId varchar(50)='All States'       /*All states*/
```

**`Select .... Where TitleFlag=@TitleFlag and`**

Now I want to specify conditions based on parameters like -

1. If not 'ALL COMPANIES' then ***upper(Company)=upper(@CompName)***
2. If not 'ALL OFFICES' then ***OfficeID=@CompBranchId***
3. If not 'ALL States' then ***StateID=@StateID***

How do I merge all of these conditions within where condition of select statement depending upon parameter value?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks Eric, 

I already used that but that takes too much time

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
where
(upper(Company)=upper(@CompName) or @compName = 'ALL COMPANIES')
and 
(OfficeID=@CompBranchId or @CompBranchId = 'ALL OFFICES')
and
(StateID=@StateID or @StateID = 'ALL States')
```

Comment: Thanks,
 but it seems you have not understood the problem.
If  @compName = 'ALL COMPANIES' then no need to add condition, if @StateID = 'ALL States' then no need to add condition etc.

Comment: @Irfan, methinks you have not understood the solution. :)  You can't dynamically change the where clause without using dynamic SQL (not recommended). What you can do is make sure that when the default string is passed the usual where clause is bypassed.  That's where "OR" comes in.  "Either the default was passed in OR the company names match."  

Try the solution before naysaying it.

Comment: That's precisely what the code suggested above does. If @compName = 'ALL COMPANIES', then that will qualify every row. Otherwise, it will evaluate upper(Company) = upper(@compName). Same for the other two parameter columns.

Comment: Yeah friend,
 you are correct. I got the solution. I must try the solution before naysaying it. Sorry for that. Thanks again...